# How to combine specific values of two variables into a new variable (?)

Tags: r, combinations, recode

I am trying to merge / combine specific values of two variables into a new variable.

The two variables to be combined:
`AL.INCOME` -> (dichotomous, whereas 1 indicates that an individual is in the 1st to 4th income decile (= poor) and 2 indicates that an individual is in the 7th or 10th income decile (= rich), other income deciles = NA)

`AL.SKILL` -> (dichotomous, whereas 1 indicates that an individual is low skilled, 2 indicates that an individual is high skilled, and else = NA)

Out of these I want to combine another dichotomous variable where 1 denotes all individuals that are poor and AT THE SAME TIME less skilled, and 2 denotes all individuals that are rich and AT THE SAME TIME high skilled, whereas all other individuals that don't fulfill both criteria are classified as NA.
The name of this new variable shall be AL.INCOME.SKILL.

Both variables refer to the same subjects (693 observations, which is the subsample "Albania" out of the ESS6 2012).

I am sorry in advance if this is a very basic question that I'm asking here and I am not using the correct terminology for certain expressions. I'm quite new to R and programming in general.

---

I have already tried to combine the variables with recode (from library car) and by building a data frame (that consists only of the two variables AL.INCOME & AL.SKILL)

```
## This is how I created AL.INCOME (dichotomous):
AlbanienVar$AL.INCOME <- recode(AlbanienVar$hinctntaAL, "1:4=1;7:10=2;else=NA")

## This is how I created AL.SKILL (dichotomous):
AlbanienVar$AL.SKILL <- recode(AlbanienVar$isco08AL, "7000:9629=1;1000:2659=2;else=NA")

##The data frame I already computed:
Trial1 <- as.data.frame(AL.INCOME, AL.SKILL)
```

---

As a remark: `AL.SKILL` contains NAs, whereas `AL.INCOME` does not. I hope this is not an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like a solution to your problem?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(AL.INCOME = c(1, 2, 2), AL.SKILL = c(1, 2, NA))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_cat = ifelse(sum(AL.INCOME, AL.SKILL) %in% c(2, 4), AL.INCOME, NA))
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   AL.INCOME AL.SKILL new_cat
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1         1        1       1
#> 2         2        2       2
#> 3         2       NA      NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried this out, it worked (I got exactly the same output as you). Yet the problem is that the tibble contains three _observations_ for the two variables, whereas I would need a variable with three possible _values_ (1, 2, NA) where my 693 oberservations can be classified in, according to their values in AL.INCOME and AL.SKILL. Or am overlooking something?

Comment: I don't think I completely understand you. Can you please re-explain how your version of tibble would differ from mine through an example?

Comment: Hey, I just decided to leave this part out of my thesis. So I guess we can leave this aside. But thank you anyway!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your thesis!